# Trying to understand "tns_alias"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

What would be tns_alias on this syntax?

```
sqlplus -L user_name/Password@tns_alias @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit, it is what is referred to in the previously cited doc as a 'net service name'.  Let's say you have a database instance named 'orcl'.  On the client server you'd have a tnsnames.ora file with an entry (net service name) something like this:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydbservername)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

then your connection would be

```
sqlplus username/password@orcl
```

When sqlnet gets the request from the client (in this case, sqlplus) it looks in tnsnames.ora for the information for 'orcl'. It then puts together a tcp packet to be sent to HOST = mydbservername, on PORT=1521.  There should be on oracle listener on mydbservername, listening for incoming requests on port 1521. When it gets the request it sees that it is for SERVICE_NAME=orcl, and, if it knows about a database posting a service name of 'orcl' it will set up the connection.

You might want to review both the [Net Services Administrator's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/toc.htm), and a series I wrote on Oracle Networking at [edstevensdba.com](http://edstevensdba.com/blog-article-index/)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to connection info stored in a tnsnames file, check pages like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260) for more info.